# Show that the roots of the equation $x^2-4abx+(a^2+2b^2)^2=0$ are imaginary.

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics

Show that the roots of the equation $x^2-4abx+(a^2+2b^2)^2=0$ are imaginary.

My Attempt:
$$x^2-4abx+(a^2+2b^2)^2=0$$
Comparing above equation with $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$, we get
\begin{align}
A&=1 \\
B&=-4ab \\
C&=(a^2+2b^2)^2
\end{align}
Now,
\begin{align}
B^2-4AC
&=(-4ab)^2 - 4\cdot 1\cdot (a^2+2b^2)^2 \\
&=16a^2b^2 - 4(a^4+4a^2b^2+4b^4) \\
&=-4a^4-16b^4. \end{align}

Comment: Thus the discriminant is negative (assuming that $a$, $b$, and $c$ are real), which means you're done, yes?  What is the question?

Comment: The problem does not say $a,b$ are real... so perhaps any correct answer must add that condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If  $a=b=0$ and the root is $0$.

However, if $(a,b) \neq 0$, then

the discriminant is equal to $-4(a^4+4b^4)<0$, hence the roots are imaginary.

Comment: Well, *technically* $0\in\mathbb R \subset \mathbb C$...

Comment: True, thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $ab\ne 0$.

Let $f (x) $ be your quadric.

$$\lim_{\infty}f (x)=+\infty $$
thus the roots will not be real if the minimum is $$f (c)>0$$ where $c $ is such that $$f'(c)=0.$$

$$f'(x)=2x-4ab \implies c=2ab $$
$$\implies f (c)=$$
$$4a^2b^2-8a^2b^2+(a^2+2b^2)^2=$$
$$(a^2+2b^2+2ab)(a^2+2b^2-2ab) =$$
$$((a+b)^2+b^2)((a-b)^2+b^2)>0$$
Done!